# AspxCheckbox List Selected Items are not deleted based on the selecteditems in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I want to remove single or grouped selected items from the AspxCheckbox list control(devexpress control) by button click. I am using the following code. It deleted the first single selected item fine. When I select 5 items(index 5, 6, 7,8) among 10. it starts to delete from 5th position to top positioned items(index 5, 4, 3)  which are not selected. Please help me fix this.

```
protected void cbpNDTStaffs_Callback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.CallbackEventArgsBase e)
    {
        if (e.Parameter == "RemoveNDTStaff")
        {
            string Message = string.Empty;

            int i;
            for (i = 0; i <= ChklstNDTStaffs.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                string EmpIDAndName = string.Empty;
                string EID = "";
                if (ChklstNDTStaffs.SelectedItems[i].Selected)
                {
                    EmpIDAndName = Convert.ToString(ChklstNDTStaffs.SelectedItems[i].Text);
                    EID = Convert.ToString(ChklstNDTStaffs.SelectedItems[i].Value);

                    Int64 ReturnValue = DataAccess.NDTDataAccess.UpdateNDTStaffs(EID, CurrentlyLoggedUserName);

                    if (ReturnValue > 0)
                    {
                        Message = "Selected NDT Staff(s) Removed Successfully.";
                    }
                }
            }

            if (Message.Length > 0)
            {
                ChklstNDTStaffs.DataBind();
                cbpNDTStaffs.JSProperties["cpIsUpdated"] = Message;
            }
            else
            {
                cbpNDTStaffs.JSProperties["cpIsUpdated"] = "";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i <= ChklstNDTStaffs.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            string EmpIDAndName = string.Empty;
            string EID = "";
            if (ChklstNDTStaffs.Items[i].Selected==true)
            {
                EmpIDAndName = Convert.ToString(ChklstNDTStaffs.Items[i].Text);
                EID = Convert.ToString(ChklstNDTStaffs.Items[i].Value);

                Int64 ReturnValue = DataAccess.NDTDataAccess.UpdateNDTStaffs(EID, CurrentlyLoggedUserName);

                if (ReturnValue > 0)
                {
                    Message = "Selected NDT Staff(s) Removed Successfully.";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Kaushik. But I couldn't get the required result. My problem is, in AspxCheckBoxList If I am selecting items from the bottom then click remove button then it is working fine. In other case if I select items from the beginning to remove then the first most record only deleted successfully remaining not gets deleted. instead of that some unselected Items are deleted. My understanding is after deleting the first item, its index is changed so for the second item aspxcheckboxlist can't able to delete the proper selected item. Is my understanding is correct? pls guide me to handle this